# Error: Cannot determine the module for component Page

Tags: angular, ionic2

Everything was working great, today I wanted to build with "ionic build ios" -I builded this app a lot of time in the past- but now I'm getting the

> Error: Cannot determine the module for component GamePage!

How can I fix/debug this ?

Here is my app.module.ts

```typescript
import {NgModule, ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler} from 'ionic-angular';
import {MyApp} from './app.component';
import {AboutPage} from '../pages/about/about';
import {ContactPage} from '../pages/contact/contact';
import {HomePage} from '../pages/home/home';
import {TabsPage} from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import {LoginPage} from "../pages/login/login";
import {GamePage} from "../pages/game/game";
import {ShopPage} from "../pages/shop/shop";
import {RegisterPage} from "../pages/register/register";


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        TabsPage,
        LoginPage,
        GamePage,
        ShopPage,
        RegisterPage
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        TabsPage,
        LoginPage,
        GamePage,
        ShopPage,
        RegisterPage
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}

    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And here is my tsconfig.json :

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/app/*.ts",
    "src/pages/*.ts",
    "www/assets/app/**/*.ts"
    //"www/assets/app/**/**/*.ts"

  ],

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"/*,
    "www/assets/app/modules/exlude"*/
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

and finaly my game.ts

```typescript
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, MenuController, IonicApp} from 'ionic-angular';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

import {Lavoisier_ionic} from "../../../www/assets/app/Lavoisier_ionic";
import {MenuGame} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_menu_game/mod_menu_game";
import {Background} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_background/mod_background";
import {DataGuardian} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_data_guardian/mod_data_guardian";
import {Auth} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_auth/mod_auth";
import {User} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_user/mod_user";
import {StartGame} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_start_game/mod_start_game";
import {MenuInGame} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_menu_ingame/mod_menu_ingame";
import {Body} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_body/mod_body";
import {MenuCasClinique} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_menu_cas_clinique/mod_menu_cas_clinique";
import {DossierPatient} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_dossier_patient/mod_dossier_patient";
import {Hypothese} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_hypothese/mod_hypothese";
import {InterrogatoirePlayground} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_interrogatoire_playground/mod_interrogatoire_playground";
import {Interrogatoire} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_interrogatoire/mod_interrogatoire";
import {ExamenPhysique} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_examen_physique/mod_examen_physique";
import {ConstantesVitales} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_constantes_vitales/mod_constantes_vitales";
import {Scoring} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_scoring/mod_scoring";
import {Bilan} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_bilan/mod_bilan";
import {Countdown} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_countdown/mod_countdown";
import {Correct} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_correct/mod_correct";
import {Diagnostic} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_diagnostic/mod_diagnostic";
import {ActionsDangereuses} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_actions_dangereuses/mod_actions_dangereuses";
import {EndGame} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_end_game/mod_end_game";
import {Exploration} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_exploration/mod_exploration";
import {ExplorationPlayground} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_exploration_playground/mod_exploration_playground";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {Fondamental} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_fondamental/mod_fondamental";
import {Help} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_help/mod_help";
import {MesuresUrgencesPlayground} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_mesures_urgences_playground/mod_mesures_urgences_playground";
import {MesuresUrgences} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_mesures_urgences/mod_mesures_urgences";
import {LowTime} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_low_time/mod_low_time";
import {NotePad} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_notepad/mod_notepad";
import {OpenNotePad} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_button_open_notepad/mod_button_open_notepad";
import {SaveDB} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_savedb/mod_savedb";
import {Modal} from "../../../www/assets/app/modules/mod_modal/mod_modal";
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
/*
 Generated class for the Game page.

 See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
 Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'page-game',
    templateUrl: 'game.html',
    providers: [Storage]
})
export class GamePage {

    lavoisier_ionic: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, storage: Storage, public http: Http, public menuCtrl: MenuController,app:IonicApp) {
        var that = this;
        var publickey;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            storage.get('publickey').then((val) => {

                publickey = val;
                that.lavoisier_ionic = new Lavoisier_ionic(http,app,navCtrl);
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new DataGuardian(that.lavoisier_ionic, http, publickey));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Auth(that.lavoisier_ionic, http, publickey));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new User(that.lavoisier_ionic, http));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Background(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new MenuGame(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new StartGame(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Body(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new MenuCasClinique(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new MenuInGame(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new DossierPatient(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Hypothese(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new InterrogatoirePlayground(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Interrogatoire(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new ExamenPhysique(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new ConstantesVitales(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Scoring(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Bilan(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Countdown(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Correct(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Diagnostic(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new ActionsDangereuses(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new EndGame(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Exploration(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new ExplorationPlayground(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Fondamental(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Help(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new MesuresUrgencesPlayground(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new MesuresUrgences(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new LowTime(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new NotePad(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new OpenNotePad(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new Modal(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.addModule(new SaveDB(that.lavoisier_ionic));
                that.lavoisier_ionic.init();
                that.lavoisier_ionic.render();
            });
        });


    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue !!! I was importing an angular component in a non-angular module. As the error said : Cannot determine the module for component GamePage!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had three classes with same name (added by Team Member) and imported only one. I had to change the names and import remainings in AppModule. Then the issue was resolved.

I believe whenever we add any Component, Directive, Pipe either we use that or not, then we must add to the imports otherwise this error will appear.